# How do I solve this level 72 question in Think Different?

Tags: think-different

I have been stuck on level 72 for a while, how do I solve this level?

```
36   1216 48

24   824  72

42   ??   51
```

[image: picture of puzzle]

Comment: Anybody want to explain their downvote? I don't see a reason for them.

Comment: Anyone want to explain their upvote?  I don't see a reason for them.  Works both ways, dude.  The point being, votes don't have to explained.  Trying to make people explain them doesn't work.  Just assume [Tim lost his keys again](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/215379/should-drive-by-downvoting-be-more-effectively-caught/215397#215397)

Comment: @Frank I know. But when I see downvotes I see no clear reason to, I tend to ask anyways. Just in case the question could be improved upon somehow.

Comment: Hey guys I opened this account to get an answer. I'm logged in with my phone so this is the best thing I could do . I tried to put a screenshot but I couldn't . So down vote it as much as you want I just need an answer :)

Comment: I think adding an image would help a lot :-) @SophiaMenacho

Comment: Done :)  so I guess you could help me now ? :))

Comment: @Wingzero most of the questions i see for this tag start out with a picture, and then someone edits it out

Comment: I see a mixture of responses here.  Some responders improved the question and others trolled the asker.  http://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice  "Be welcoming, be patient, and assume good intentions."

Comment: The image looks nice and causes no harm, so there is no reason to remove it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The numbers in the middle are all determined by dividing the numbers on each side by 3, and joining them together.

**First line:** 36 / 3 = 12; 48 / 3 = 16; **1216**. 
**Second line:** 24 / 3 = 8; 72 / 3 = 24; **824**. 
**Third line:** 42 / 3 = 14 ; 51 / 3 = 17; **1417**.

**The solution is 1417**.